# rbenv equivalent of rvm's named rubies

Tags: ruby, rbenv

In rvm, you can do [named rubies](https://rvm.io/rubies/named/) . That is, you can give your own name to the ruby implementation.

Is it possible to do this in rbenv, preferably using `rbenv install` (which calls ruby-build)?

**Background:** I've currently got 1.9.3-p194 and 1.8.7-p358 installed. Installing 1.9.1-p378 would mean an extra tab when doing `rbenv shell 1.9.3-p194`, unless I could give 1.9.1-p378 a different name.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I get you.  Let's say I'm sick of typing jruby tab, tab.  So I want to rename jruby to foo.

```
$ cd $HOME/.rbenv/versions
$ mv jruby-1.6.7 foo-1.6.7
$ rbenv prefix foo-1.6.7
~/.rbenv/versions/foo-1.6.7
$ rbenv shell foo-1.6.7 
$ ruby -v
jruby 1.6.7 (ruby-1.8.7-p357) ...
$ rbenv versions
  1.8.7-p358
  1.9.3-p125
  1.9.3-p194
* foo-1.6.7 (set by RBENV_VERSION environment variable)
```

Doing another install of jruby at this point makes rbenv redownload jruby-1.6.7 and now I have two copies of JRuby 1.6.7 (luckily this is what you want).  The tab completion works too.  So this might be what you want.  Not sure if it has any side effects.

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple for rbenv. Just use a symlink:

```
% rbenv versions     
* 1.9.3-p327 (set by /Users/mark/.rbenv/version)
  2.0.0-preview1
  2.0.0-preview2

% ln -s ~/.rbenv/versions/1.9.3-p327 ~/.rbenv/versions/1.9       
% rbenv versions                                          
  1.9
* 1.9.3-p327 (set by /Users/mark/.rbenv/version)
  2.0.0-preview1
  2.0.0-preview2
% rbenv shell 1.9
% ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p327 (2012-11-10 revision 37606) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]
% rbenv versions                                          
* 1.9 (set by RBENV_VERSION environment variable)
  1.9.3-p327
  2.0.0-preview1
  2.0.0-preview2
```

Simple as that!